# CTL - Central limit theorem, how to use it in R?

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I've learned the CTL, and I have a question.

There is an average of 100 observations when the expectation is M and the Variance is 9.

I need to find the a&b Top block and bottom block, that the probability will be bigger than 0.9.

```
p( a <= x(100)-M <= b ) >= 0.9
```

the X(100) is x with 100 tries.

How I do this in R? I can't understand.. I wrote something like this -

```
numt <- 1:100
cbind(numt , 1-2*pnorm(-b/3))
```

but I understand it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand if the following is what the question asks for.
The following function takes as input

1. `M` - expectation,
2. `Var` - variance,
3. `n` - the sample size,
4. `prob` the two-sided probability.

Arguments `Var`, `n` and `prob` have the defaults in the question, so this can be seen as a function of `M` only.

```
fun <- function(M, Var = 9, n = 100, prob = 0.90){
  p <- c((1 - prob)/2, 1 - (1 - prob)/2)
  qq <- qnorm(p, mean = M, sd = sqrt(Var/n))
  setNames(qq, c("lower", "upper"))
}

M <- 1
fun(M)
#    lower     upper 
#0.5065439 1.4934561
```

Comment: no, I have 100 observations. i need to find a, and b. I don't need to do a histograma, I just need to find a, b with CTL sentence.

Comment: Is it make sense that the upper is bigger than 1? And bigger than 0.9?

Comment: @JohnJohn Yes, it does make sense. If `M` is 1 like in the example, the upper limit must be greater than 1. And if `M` were 0, with a variance of 9 the interval is larger than with a variance of 1. Even with a variance equal to 1 the upper limit of a 90% CI is greater than 1.

Comment: don't we need to see this like binom with 200 tries?

Comment: @JohnJohn No, the CLT does not include a distributional condition. That the binomial converges to the normal when np is held constant is a different matter. What my answer gives is the CI for the mean of a sample of length `n` of a random variable with known mean `M` and known variance `Var`. The distribution of the random variable is not known, could be a binomial or any other.